# How to avoid double window opening at launch?

Tags: cocoa, macos, cocos2d-iphone

I've been porting my cocos2D iOS game to Mac and it works without problems but I don't understand why I get two windows open every time I launch the app.

One of them is the cocos2d window with the main menu scene and the properties and name I give but there is another blank white window with the app name (I mean the Xcode project name). I suppose this is a trivial issue but I really can't avoid that window from appearing.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my AppDelegate window initialization:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{

CCDirectorMac *director = (CCDirectorMac*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    //Posiciona ventana y define escalado

     NSRect aFrame=[[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];

CGSize winSize = CGSizeMake(1024,768);

CC_DIRECTOR_INIT(winSize);
[self.window showsResizeIndicator];

[director setResizeMode:kCCDirectorResize_AutoScale];
[director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];

[window_ setContentAspectRatio:NSMakeSize(winSize.width,winSize.height)];
[window_ setStyleMask:[window_ styleMask] | NSResizableWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask];
[window_ setTitle:@"Barman Hero"];

aFrame=[[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
if (aFrame.size.width<=winSize.width || aFrame.size.height<=winSize.height) [window_ zoom:self];
[window_ center];
[glView_ setFrameSize:NSMakeSize(window_.frame.size.width,window_.frame.size.height-22)]; 

// Enable "moving" mouse event. Default no.
[window_ setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:NO];
```

.....

.....

.....

```
//Carga escena principal
[[CCDirectorMac sharedDirector] runWithScene:[MainMenu scene]];
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are `self.window` and `window_` the same object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that you have a Window defined in `MainMenu.xib` that is being opened semi-automatically. Remove the window from `MainMenu.xib` and any code that might reference it and it should no longer open the second window.

Comment: Thanks Percy, but I don't have any MainMenu.xib in my project. In fact, I don't have any xib file at all.

Comment: @rmvz3: Check again. An application does not implicitly create a window, so the only two possible reasons that window would exist are that either you are creating it in code or you have it in a nib that is being loaded (most probably MainMenu, which is loaded automatically). As of Xcode 4, MainMenu.xib is in the Supporting Files group; in Xcode 3 and possibly other older templates, it's in the Resources group. You can also look in your project folder; it'll be in the en.lproj or English.lproj folder.

Comment: YES!!. You're right!!. The MainMenu.xib was hidden into English.lproj folder and not listed in Xcode. I found it in finder, double clicked and removed window and everything is fine now. Thanks a lot for you invaluable help. :)